# Excel Formula or VBA to find next cell in a row with a wildcard value AFTER date column

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, find, formula

I am trying to make a column that shows a student's next planned event. I have some code that works but I would have to copy paste it for every single line offset and update it every time a student was added or removed. If I had a formula or code that would cover the row that wouldn't need constant updating, that'd be a huge help.

Here is a simplified version of our tracker. I had to erase info for confidentiality reasons. I want B4:B6 column to display the next event after the current date tracked by column in B3.

[image]

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE($C4:$AG4,"Fly, ",""),($C$3:$AG$3>$B$3)*($C4:$AG4<>"")),1,1),"NE")`. This assumes the last column is `AG` (change as needed). Paste this into B4 and copy down.

Comment: The above works if your version supports the `FILTER` function - check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(4:4,1,MIN(IF(""&D4:K4<>"",IF(D$2:K$2>TODAY(),COLUMN(D4:K4),999999),999998))),"")
```

Type it in C4 and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, because is an array formula.
Adapt it get the right part of the cell value if is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data you provided, this code can replicate your expected outcome.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim lRowCnt As Long, iColCnt As Long
    Dim sDate As Date, iColStart As Long
    Dim arr, res()
    arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    lRowCnt = UBound(arr)
    iColCnt = UBound(arr, 2)
    sDate = #7/4/2023#
    'sDate = Date
    If lRowCnt > 3 And iColCnt > 2 Then
        iColCnt = UBound(arr, 2)
        ReDim res(1 To lRowCnt - 3, 1 To 1)
        For j = 3 To iColCnt
            If arr(2, j) > sDate Then
                iColStart = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If iColStart > 0 Then
            For i = 4 To lRowCnt
                For j = iColStart To iColCnt
                    If Len(Trim(arr(i, j))) > 0 Then
                        res(i - 3, 1) = Trim(Split(arr(i, j), ",")(1))
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
    [B4].Resize(lRowCnt - 3, 1).Value = res
End Sub
```